# Localized WordPress content for different sub-locales of same language?

Tags: multisite, urls, localization, l10n

I have a site which serves Ireland & England. I want to move it to Wordpress.

Currently all the content is the same when you visit the site & it runs off two urls, the Irish one: mysite.ie & the english mysite.co.uk

I need to show different prices based on whether the user is visiting the Irish site or the English one. Currently I do something like:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; 
if($host == "www.mysite.ie") {
 //show Irish prices
}
```

I don't think I can run one WP installation off 2 domains for a start.

It's not multilingual, so is there a way to show all the same content except for small differences based on the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually, you *should* view your site as requiring "multilingual" capabilities, even if the base language for both countries is identical, because the actual *locale* for each is nevertheless different.

More specifically, you can create variant "translations" for your British ('en_GB') and Irish ('en_IE') localizations. A plugin such [WPML (WordPress Multilingual)](http://wpml.org) can help you implement this, and it supports different URL schemes for differentiating between the localizations, including:

- different domains (or subdomains)
- different subdirectories